# Mandate encryption on photon server

Tags: encryption, cryptography, photon

The [photon docs](http://doc.exitgames.com/en/photon-server/Encryption) state that

> In the application frameworks we provide (Lite, LoadBalancing, etc.), 
>       the server automatically responds encrypted, if an operation was sent encrypted.
>       This makes it safe to fetch critical data by simply requesting with encryption turned on.

Can it be made mandatory on the server side? So that Photon doesn't process certain events if the operation is invoked or received un-encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can check if the client sent the request encrypted in OnOperationRequest in the peer:

```
protected override void OnOperationRequest(OperationRequest request, SendParameters sendParameters)
{
...
if (!sendParameters.Encrypted)
{
    string message = string.Format("Only encrypted operations allowed.");
    var response = new OperationResponse { ReturnCode = (short)ErrorCode.OperationDenied, DebugMessage = message, OperationCode = request.OperationCode };
    this.SendOperationResponse(response, sendParameters);
    return;
}
```

You would implement your own peer and inherit from the frameworks peer, have a look at MyAppliction in Lite.

Answer (score 1):

You would simply need to trap `OnStatusChanged` for the client and upon receiving a `Connect` type status change you can invoke the `EstablishEncryption` method on the client.

This will send down the requirement that all communication is to be encrypted. You will want to discard all requests until you receive a status change of type `EncryptionEstablished` and disconnect the client if you see `EncryptionFailedToEstablish`, this gives you the functionality that no events are processed until encryption is completely established.

As far as doing this on a per operation basis, that's going to be a bit more tricky. I recommend just having everything encrypted. The overhead is minimal and it solves your problem. As far as additional CPU time or RAM utilization or network traffic, it's completely negligible.

For specifics about the implementation of this behavior, you can review [this reference](http://doc.exitgames.com/en/photon-realtime/Encryption).